# Angular2 Observable and subscribe

Tags: angular, observable

My current scenario is:
My component calls Class A which calls Class B that end up doing an http request.
Component:

```
 if (form.valid) 
   let returnvalue = this.userData.login(this.user);
```

My class A (user-data)

```
    login(user: User) {
     return this.authService.doLogin(user).subscribe(data => {
      let token:Token = data;
      this.storage.set(this.TOKEN, token);
      this.storage.set(this.HAS_LOGGED_IN, true);
      this.setUsername(user.username);
      this.events.publish('user:login');
      return data;
    }, err =>{
     console.log("error login");
      return err;
    });
```

Class B (Auth Service)

```
// DO HTTP REQUEST
    doLogin(user: User) {
        var headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': AuthProvider.basicKey });
        var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        let body = new URLSearchParams();
        body.set('username', user.username); // the user's search value
        body.set('password', user.password);
        body.set('grant_type', 'password');
        body.set('scope', 'read');
        body.set('client_secret', '123456');
        body.set('client_id', 'clientapp');
        return this.httpPost(`${AuthProvider.urlLogin}`, body, options);

      }
```

My objective is: In class B when the execution is finished, I want to pass another observable to my Component class so I would be able to show a message if the request failed or redirect page if the request was successful. How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: You labeled both as class B, can you please clarify?

Comment: @Meir, sry, I edited.